# Sample size formulae

Tags: sample-size, statistical-power, type-i-and-ii-errors

In order to calculate sample size for hypothesis testing, we consider level of significance and power. For level of significance, two sided values ($Z_{\alpha/2}$) are taken into account, but for power one sided values ($Z_{(1-β)}$) are considered. Why not take two sided values for type II error, too?

Comment: That's not how power is estimated. Where is this from?